# possible to junit test a spring rest call?

Tags: java, unit-testing, http, rest, spring-3

is it possible to test a controller that contains a rest method inside?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.PUT,consumes="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String>createNewAccount(HttpEntity<String>request) {
//do something

}
```

How would i call this method using a fake http request that sends http headers, uri and content to this method? any stubs or mock classes that do this? something like

```
httpMockRequest.consume(uri,headers, body,method, controller class);
```

which would then go into my controller and look for request mapping based on the uri and http method used and then execute and send over the http headers and content from the httpMockRequest test object?

Anything like that exists in Spring or Java EE?

I am using Spring 3 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is just to instantiate the controller and invoke the method directly to the controller. Your test should test just the implementation of the controller and not the entire flow (from Servlet to your method).

I usually do something like this on my test implementation:

```
Controller c = new Controller();
// configure controller c with mock services
ResponseEntity<String> re = c.createNewAccount(new HttpEntity<String>("{\"property\":10}"));
// check response entity (parsing json of re.getBody())
```

For headers you have this constructors:

```
HttpEntity(T body, MultiValueMap<String, String> headers)
```

And the URI itself isn't important here as it would be used just to resolve the controller and method.